# on_change in Odoo not working

Tags: python, odoo, onchange, odoo-8

I have a form with many elements. One of them being a dropdown list with name=`evaluation_id`. I am trying to create an Odoo `on_change( )` event on `evaluation_id` whereby one other element in the form - `deadline` will be updated with a certain value.

In my XML I have:

```
<field name="evaluation_id" string="Appraisal" on_change="onchange_evaluation_id(evaluation_id)"/>
```

And I have this in Python script

```
def onchange_evaluation_id(self, cr, uid, ids, evaluation_id, context=None):

    return {'value': { 'deadline': 2015}}
```

Here is the original code for the [hr_evaluation_view.XML](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3366) and snippet of the [hr_evaluation.PY](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3367) Script.

What am I doing wrong here? when I check the network log, I see that the function on_change doesn't even load.

what can I do to fix this? Any help would be nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options available in odoo to use when some changes made inside field at the moment function will be triggered.

**@api.onchange**

This decorator will trigger the call to the decorated function if any of the fields specified in the decorator is changed in the form. Here scope is limited to the same screen / model.

You may field similarities in @api.depends and @api.onchange, but the some differences are that scope of onchange is limited to the same screen / model while @api.depends works other related screen / model also.

```
@api.onchange('field')
def onchange_field(self)
    self.deadline= value
```

**@api.depends**

This decorator is specifically used for "fields.function" in odoo. For a "field.function", you can calculate the value and store it in a field, where it may possible that the calculation depends on some other field(s) of same table or some other table, in that case you can use `@api.depends` to keep a 'watch' on a field of some table.

So, this will trigger the call to the decorated function if any of the fields in the decorator is 'altered by ORM or changed in the form'.

```
@api.depends('field')
def function_name(self)
    self.deadline = value
```

For more info, [Here](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decorator.html) is the link that describe all API of Odoo v8.

Answer (score 1):

This method you can write into py file. This will work if you work on only in Odoo-v8.

```
@api.onchange('evaluation_id')
def onchange_evalution_id(self)
    self.deadline='2015'
```